# CoreMedia error 12160 (CoreMediaErrorDomain) - explanation?

Tags: ios, swift, core-media

I was unable to find the error explanation on web.

Somewhere in the mechanism of downloading licensed streams (HLS + FairPlay) the OS reports `Error Domain=CoreMediaErrorDomain Code=-12160 "(null)"` which makes downloaded movie unable to be played after download.

There must be some way to get more info about this error code. Has anyone an idea where it is defined?

Comment: Nope... I think I finally threw away my code and copy-pasted-adapted example Apple code for Fairplay and HLS Downloader and it is working better (but still not perfect)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you use a streaming license for a AVPersistableContentKeyRequest. To convert a streaming license to a persistable license do the following:

```
let pckc = try keyRequest.persistableContentKey(fromKeyVendorResponse: ckcData)
```

Then continue to passing the response to the keyRequest as normal

```
let response = AVContentKeyResponse(fairPlayStreamingKeyResponseData: pckc)
keyRequest.processContentKeyResponse(keyResponse)
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am not in the streaming project anymore and I can't check it but if I see anyone confirming that this helps I will mark the answer as accepted. Thanks for sharing